# Python line of code not running until after tkinter mainloop ends

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program I am trying to build with tkinter where the user can see data in the main window. I accomplish this using Treeview and have bound double click to open another window with further data that the user can modify for the row they double clicked. All this data is stored in a pandas dataframe. I want to give the user the ability to click on specific fields in the new window, update them and then close the window, which will save the updated fields to the dataframe. It is nearly working, however, the pandas dataframe isn't updated until after I close the main window, exiting the mainloop. The line of code to update the pandas dataframe is in a function that is bound to double click which is defined before the mainloop function, so I am confused as to why this wouldn't work.

I know the after() method is used to delay time based events, but I want to update data based on when the user closes the popup window after they've modified all the data they'd like for said data row. I stumbled across .update() and .update_idletasks(), which in the examples I've seen, don't seem to apply to my situation.

Please help.

Edit:

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. My actual code is a bit of a mess atm and may distract from the actual issue. When I press the button a new window opens up (root2) and upon closing, shouldn't it exit out of the root2.mainloop() and then execute the following line, being the print(my_stuff.loc['Z','A'])? All of these prints seem to get staged somewhere in the background and they do not run until I close the main window (root).

Basically, I want some arbitrary code to be executed after the user closes the pop-up window in order to take the information the user provided in the pop-up window and do something with it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd


my_stuff = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])


def button_pushed():
    root2 = tk.Toplevel()
    root2.grab_set()
    root2.mainloop()
    print(my_stuff.loc['Z','A'])


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Push Me', command=button_pushed)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"Python line of code not running until after tkinter mainloop ends"_ - yes, that is how it is designed to work. `mainloop` won't return until the window has been destroyed.

Comment: How can we identify the issue without a [mre]?

Comment: I thought that may happen. I put together an analogous script to hopefully help communicate the issue and my goal.

Comment: Only execute `mainloop()` once in a tkinter application, therefore remove `root2.mainloop()`.  If you want to wait until the secondary window closes, call `root2.wait_window()` instead.